# Azure pipeline build go modules correctly

Tags: go, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, go-modules

Because the default azure-pipelines.yml template for building go code does not support go modules it is not obvious how it would look like to support it.

This is the default template which is not working for go.modules:

```
# Go
# Build your Go project.
# Add steps that test, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/go

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  GOBIN:  '$(GOPATH)/bin' # Go binaries path
  GOROOT: '/usr/local/go1.11' # Go installation path
  GOPATH: '$(system.defaultWorkingDirectory)/gopath' # Go workspace path
  modulePath: '$(GOPATH)/src/github.com/$(build.repository.name)' # Path to the module's code

steps:
- script: |
    mkdir -p '$(GOBIN)'
    mkdir -p '$(GOPATH)/pkg'
    mkdir -p '$(modulePath)'
    shopt -s extglob
    shopt -s dotglob
    mv !(gopath) '$(modulePath)'
    echo '##vso[task.prependpath]$(GOBIN)'
    echo '##vso[task.prependpath]$(GOROOT)/bin'
  displayName: 'Set up the Go workspace'

- script: |
    go version
    go get -v -t -d ./...
    if [ -f Gopkg.toml ]; then
        curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golang/dep/master/install.sh | sh
        dep ensure
    fi
    go build -v .
  workingDirectory: '$(modulePath)'
  displayName: 'Get dependencies, then build'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to share also the answer here for a template that builds a go modules package correctly. Maybe this is just for your inspiration what needs to be considered. It took me some time to get there.

The main pain point is that the the default template sets the GOPATH to the pipeline workingdirectory which is just wrong if you will download modules via `go mod download` into it. This would lead to inaccesible files in the next pipeline run, making the pipeline failing during repository checkout.

The following approach just sets GOPATH to the Agent.HomeDirectory which also makes downloaded modules available for subsequent pipeline runs.

Maybe it helps someone

```
# Go
# Build your Go project.
# Add steps that test, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/go

trigger: 
- main
- feature/*

pool: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  GOPATH: '$(Agent.HomeDirectory)/go' # Go workspace path
  GOBIN:  '$(GOPATH)/bin' # Go binaries path
  GOROOT: '/opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.15.8/x64' # Go installation path
  

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build image
  
  jobs:  
  - job: BuildAndTest
    displayName: Build And Test
    pool: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - script: |
        export PATH="$(GOROOT)/bin:$(PATH)"
        printenv
        ls -la
        go env
        go version
        go mod download
        go build ./...
        go test ./... 
      workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
      displayName: 'Get dependencies, then build and test'
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The .yml file from [learn.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/go?view=azure-devops&tabs=go-current) works, but it requires that go.mod and main.go be in the root directory.  The pipeline should support the typical go project structure with a `cmd/main.go`, `pkg/`, and `internal/` directories